# Type of book written by L.M Alcott

Tags: history-of-literature, terminology, louisa-may-alcott

Somewhere or other, many years ago, I read that there was a name for the type of book written by the likes of L.M. Alcott. That they were a backlash against the novels of the time and meant to teach moral lessons.

**Is this true, and is there a name for the genre?**

Answer (score 2):

The "Little Women" series is foremost a *bildungsroman*, literally 'education novel' from the German (where it originated, in the first half of the 18th century), meaning a 'coming of age' narrative in which the protagonist(s) mature in either or both age, wisdom and/or morality. Morality is a **very** significant part of this genre and the progression of the protagonist(s) to (a) moral and wise character(s) is depicted as a key part to the narrative. This can be exemplified in Jo's heartbreaking rejection of Laurie's marriage proposal, in which she shows wisdom far beyond her years as she recognises that Laurie's fierce passion for her is not a good basis for a marriage. Instead she eventually marries Professor Bhaer, an older but a much more sensible husband than the charming but impulsive Laurie. This is a stark contrast to Joe's characteristic of being somewhat childish (in a good way!) behaviour seen earlier in the novel, such as her over-enthusiastic renditions of plays. She also metamorphoses from being rebellious, outspoken and often angry to a profoundly psychologically mature woman.

This psychological progression of Jo's is characteristic of the *bildungsroman* genre. Dickens is another novelist who widely uses this technique, especially in *Great Expectations* and *Oliver Twist*. In terms of L.M Alcott's novels being a backlash to immoral works of the period, this **could** be referring to the boom in Gothic or [Sensation Novels](https://www.britannica.com/art/English-literature/Late-Victorian-literature#ref308678) in the 1850s-60s which were written to achieve the goal of shocking and scaring readers. Charles Darwin's *The Origin of Species* was also written in this period which was and still is a controversial work. Her novels remained innocent, as a silent protest to her contemporaries. 
For more about the *bildungsroman* genre, [this site](https://global.britannica.com/art/bildungsroman) explains it well.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. I've been impressed with your contributions so far, but it's always a good idea to cite sources. As a reader who knows nothing about the topic but would want to verify what you write here, citing a source that describes the history of the bildungsroman genre and the genres qualities would be very helpful.

Comment: Sure, sorry! Added link :)

Comment: sorry to nitpick so much, but do you have a more reputable link? That website has the same problem; it doesn't have a reputable source.

Answer (score 0):

One type of novel written by L. M. Alcott was the *suspense novel*.  The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Long_Fatal_Love_Chase) on her *A Long Fatal Love Chase* describes the plot

> ...a discontented maiden who lives on an English island with only her bitter old grandfather for company and who begins the novel by rashly declaring: "I often feel as if I'd gladly sell my soul to Satan for a year of freedom." Right on cue, a man...

Is this what you mean?

Comment: No, I am talking more about the likes of 'eight cousins' and the 'little woman' series.

Comment: Oh. Have you read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Women) whose *Reception* section bandies phrases like *literature for self-authorization* and *women's fiction was being idealized with a "hearth and home" children's story*.

Comment: Interesting. I find it a little difficult to get my head around the slight feminist spin that that section seems to be placing on the book though. But I may be falling into the same trap that I generally despise of judging old morality by modern standards.

Comment: So I suppose "hearth and home" is a possible answer to your original question.  *Little Women* seems to have been a turning point in kid lit that has  evoked complex responses over the passage of time: it is no surprise that modern commentators use a modern terminology in discussing it.  I have no trouble in thinking of *Little Women* as a novel of agency, even though the term is a modern one.  With regard to your original question: Would you class it with the L.M. Montgomery books, or Jean Webster's books, with LMA's LW?

Comment: I haven't read any L.M. Montgomery. I have actually been thinking about it a lot since your last comment. And I can definitely see the validity. I think my mind actually was just closed to the idea, perhaps because I first read them as a very young child, perhaps I was just being ignorant.

Comment: On rethinking my previous opinions, I can definitely  see the remarkably liberal overtones (for the time). Not quite as overt as Webster, but she was writing 50-odd years earlier, long before the active first wave of feminism which formed the backdrop for Webster. Now I noticing things like the university in Jo's Boys which allows women to attend along with men.

Comment: And Mrs March encouraging Meg, in Good Wives, to take an interest in politics and other such 'masculine' things, in order to spend more time with her husband. Or, the same in the same, for Meg to allow John to have some part in child-rearing, and how successful he is with Demijohn.

Comment: Or Phebe, a servant in Rose In Bloom, being accepted into the high-society Campbell's, after proving her own capability and earning the respect of the aunts. This perhaps shows more social mobility than anything else, but that too was a liberal idea in those times.

Comment: Forgive the essay, it sums up as 'I was wrong.'